# Relation between QtGui and QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qtgui

Here is the .h file :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow();

private:
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

With the .h file, I get the error :

```
expected class-name before '{' token in Qt
```

I can add `#include <QMainWindow>` and the error disappear, but I don't understand why. Should `QtGui` include `QMainWindow`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're encountering.  There must be something else wrong.  `QtGui` does include `QMainWindow`.

Comment: That's quite strange. I tried it with other classes (QMenuBar, QAction, ...) and it seems like QtGui doesn't include them as well.

Comment: btw. you forgot to add Q_OBJECT on your class

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The QtGui doesn't include QMainWindow anymore because the widgets are in a different module, in Qt5.

The file listing "includes" for the widgets is QtWidgets/QtWidgets.

Comment: Ok, so you tell me that if I want to include everything, I have to do #include <QtGui> and #include <QtWidgets>?